# Need to learn Javascript integration with Salesforce

Tags: javascript, api

Are there any materials in which I can learn how to do integration with Salesforce api using Javascript?

Comment: Search StackExchange or Google 'JS Remoting' and you will find an abundance of articles and resources that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of examples out there. Take a peek at the [AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/) for starters, and you can also look at the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) if you're already familiar with using XMLHttpRequest or you're using some library, like jQuery, that already provides AJAX capabilities.